# Can't get <button> to be to the right of textbox

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I am trying to have the button to display to the right of the textbox but it's displaying to the bottom in IE7.

```
<div style="margin-top: 12px; border: 1px red solid" >
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearh" name="txtSearch" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
          <button id="Search" accesskey="s" type="submit" runat="server" onserverclick="Search_Click" style="display: inline;float: left">
            <span><u>S</u>earch</span></button>
        </div>
```

Comment: Where's the code? This is nowhere near enough to go on.

Comment: You have the textbox, the button and a div wrapper. What code do you need?

Comment: check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29341443/2218697), hope helps someone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this style attribute from your `<button>`:

```
style="display: inline;float: left"
```

A `<button>` is an inline element by default so you don't need `display:inline` and the `float:left` is what is making the button wrap to the next line.

Comment: And if it still wraps it means there isn't enough container width available to display the button next to the textbox. Make it wider or make the textbox and/or button smaller.

Comment: I added the float in the last minute and because I didn't see a change, I left it. The culprit was a css file that changed the behavior of the button element plus a missing css file to fix IE. The html was working fine in FF. I thought it was an IE problem .problem.