# How to align a button to the right of text box without margin?

Tags: html, css, layout

How can I align a button (submit) exactly to the right of a text or search box, 
with the same height as the search box, 
and **without** any horizontal white-space between search box and button ?

This is what I have

```
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="search text here" style="display: block;  width: 100px; height: 32px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; float: left;" />
<input type="submit" value=" OK "  style="display: block; margin: 0px;  width: 20px; height: 32px; padding: 0px; float: left; border-left: none;" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ggg2b/

But neither is the button the same height as the textbox
<del>, and more importantly, I don't seem to be able to get rid of that 0.5 to 1mm space between text-box and button.</del>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I got it.

There are two problems at once.
First, there may be no white-space between end of input 1 and start of input 2.
A known IE bug.

And then, for the buttons being the same size as the text-box, it's necessary to apply the box-sizing property

```
-moz-box-sizing: content-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
box-sizing: content-box;
```

Like this:

```
label, input  {
    margin: 0.1em 0.2em;
    padding: 0.3em 0.4em;
    border: 1px solid #f90;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;

    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;

}

input[type=text] {
    margin-right: 0;
    border-radius: 0.6em 0 0 0.6em;
}
input[type=text]:focus {
    outline: none;
    background-color: #ffa;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,210,0.5);
}
input[type=submit] {
    margin-left: 0;
    border-radius: 0 0.6em 0.6em 0;
    background-color: #aef;
}
input[type=submit]:active,
input[type=submit]:focus {
    background-color: #acf;
    outline: none;
}



<form action="#" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="something" id="something" /><input type="submit" value="It's a button!" />

</form>
```

Comment: this is some thing i never used. :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
     <input type="text" value="" placeholder="search text here" class="txtbox" />
     <input type="submit" value=" OK "  class="btncls" />

        .txtbox{
            display: block;
            float: left;
            height: 32px;
            width: 100px;
        }

        .btncls{
            display: block;
            float: left;
            height: 40px;
            margin: -1px -2px -2px;
            width: 41px;
        }
```

OR Check on Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ggg2b/9/

Comment: Not the same height in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Add a height to the button using CSS.

```
.btn {
     font-size: 16px;
     border: 0;           
     height: 34px;
     margin: 0;         
     float:left;
    }
```

Then add height to the `textbox` using `style` attribute and check whether the heights match.

```
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="search text here" style="height:28px;float:left;margin:0;" />
<input type="submit" value=" OK "  class='btn' />
```

fiddle demo:http://jsfiddle.net/suhailvs0/Ggg2b/7/

Comment: @Quandary you can easity remove the white spaces by putting `margin:0;` for text box ie `<input type="text" value="" placeholder="search text here" style="height:28px;margin:0;float:left;" />` also add float:left to `.btn`. i updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To show your submit button at the right side of your search you only need to change some of your code as per given below. remove the left align from the code of button. and give the to the button is 34 px

```
 <input type="text" value="" placeholder="search text here" style="display: block;  width: 100px; height: 32px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; float: left;" />
        <input type="submit" value=" OK "  style="display: block; margin: 0px;  width: 40px; height: 34px; padding: 0px; " />
```

Comment: That doesn't render any different than the original code, it's not the same size,  and there is white-space as well.

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this is by putting the text input and the button in a container which uses grid layout. Using the below simple code, you will need to add width restraints on the container as it will expand to the max possible width:

```css
.joined {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="joined">
  <input type="text"></input>
  <button>Go</button>
</section>
```

Here is an example showing how it will autosize/grow with other size settings applied:

```css
.joined-2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
  
  min-width:280px;
  width: 80vw;
}

input {
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<section class="joined-2">
  <input type="text"></input>
  <button>Go</button>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

put this in a paragrapgh tag and there no need for float:left

```
 <p><input type="text" value="" placeholder="search text here" style="display: block;  width: 100px;        height: 32px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" />
 <input type="submit" value=" OK "  style="display: block; margin: 0px;  width: 20px; height: 32px; padding: 0px; " /></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase the width, say for example

`<input type="submit" value=" OK "  style="display: block; margin: 0px;  width: 100px; height: 32px; padding: 0px; float: left;" />`

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with width. If you increase the width of the button, it's just wider, the white-space in-between persists. That's because there may be no white-space between end of input 1 and start of input 2. A known IE bug. And the problem with the height is the box-sizing mode. Increasing the width solves neither problem.

Answer (score 0):

Put them into a container, set fix `width` and `height` of the container. And set the elements in the container only `percentage` width. If you will use `border-box: sizing;` you can add them `border` and `pagging` without change container's `width` and `height`.

HTML:

```
<div class="input-box">
    <input class="input-1" type="text" value="" placeholder="search text here"  />
    <input class="input-2" type="submit" value="OK"  />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.input-1, .input-2{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
.input-1{
    width: 70%; /* input-1 + input-2 = 100% */
}
.input-2{
    width: 30%; /* input-1 + input-2 = 100% */
}
.input-box{
    height: 32px; /* Own value - full height */
    width: 200px; /* Own value - full width */
}
```

**Live demo. Now new, edited.**

http://jsfiddle.net/Ggg2b/14/

Comment: If you remove the border from the button, then the button will lose the click effect.

Comment: You can add this border.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes in HTML markup. I wrapped the input boxes in divs and assigned width and height to the divs instead of the input boxes.

**HTML**

```
<div class="mainCls">
    <div class="textCls">
        <input type="text" value="" placeholder="search text here" />
    </div>
    <div class="submitCls">
        <input type="submit" value=" OK " />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type=text], input[type=submit] {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
}
div.mainCls {
    height: 35px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid green;
    display:inline-block;
}
.mainCls>div {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
.textCls {
    width: 100px;
}
.submitCls {
    width: 30px;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/Ggg2b/12/)**

If the input boxes are of fixed width, as in your case, then there is no need of child div's which I used above. You can just add `left: 100px; /* width of the input text */` to the `submit button`.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this same task for a search box, I hope this may help someone.

```
<input type="text" name="id" id="seacrhbox" class="form-control" 
placeholder="Type to search" style="width:300px;display:inline-block;margin-right: 25px;"/>

<input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn-success" style="height:32px; 
width:80px;font-weight: 600;" />
```

Additionaly: (not related to the question)

If you would like to retain the value of a textbox in an asp/mvc use:

`value="@Request["id"]"` but if you want to do it in html try [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-placeholder-on-focus-in-search-widget)